# Case Statement - Oracle v.11

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

New to Oracle - I would like to create a Case Statement OR INDICATOR OF SOME SORT that can identify when a client is considered "Engaged". I have the below data. I want to be able to count Per Month.

Count all Memberids for the month but also accumulate for the memberids that are still considered open. I'm not sure if this is the best platform to do this but thought I would ask. I can sum outside of SQL.

```
201607 = 4 (Memberid: 1-3 & 5)
201606 = 2 (Memberid: 4 & 5)
Total records below = 5

Start_Year_Month         EndDate       ID     Status
    201607                             1       OPEN
    201607                             2       OPEN
    201607                 201607      3       CLOSED
    201606                 201606      4       CLOSED
    201606                             5       OPEN
```

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: How do you define "Engaged"? What is the logic for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is relatively simple:

```
select m.mon, count(t.id)
from (select distinct start_year_month as mon from t) m join
     t
     on m.mon >= t.start_year_month and 
        (m.mon <= t.enddate or t.enddate is null)
group by m.mon;
```

This will not have great performance as the number of months increases (unless your data is quite small).  A more performant solution is a bit more complicated.